# Mesh always faces User Perspective when added

Tags: mesh

Whenever I try adding a new object in my scene, it always starts off facing towards the user perspective. How can I make it so that it's aligned to the grid (like the default cube) rather than my view without rotating the object?

Here is a cube that I just added using Shift-A. Unlike the default cube, it faces where my view port is pointing. 
[image: User perspective facing shape when adding]

Vs. Default cube orientation
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust it in the Preferences>>Editing>>Objects.

[image]

Or instantly at the lower left corner of the 3D View when you add new models. As Gorgious said in the comment section.
[image]

Comment: That did the trick, was not aware of this setting, thank you!

Comment: @kunaynay Alternatively when you create the object, unfold the panel in the lower left of your viewport and you can check/uncheck it there, along with some other options